# Dynamic google map creation using same division and variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps

I am trying to generate map onclick on same division and same variable "**map**" using following script, it's not functioning, I don't know how to destroy old map and recreate please someone help me.. this is what I have tried so far..

***Here is link to*** [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4QLdP/)

***JS***

```
function map(lat,lon){
  jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  var centerPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
  var options = {
    zoom: 16,
    center: centerPosition,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), options);
  });
 }

var lat =22, lon = 75;
map(lat,lon);
```

***HTML***

```
   <div id="map"></div>
   <button onclick="map(15,90)" >15 90</button>
   <button onclick="map(22,80)" >22 80</button>
```

***CSS***

```
#map {
 height: 300px;
 width: 500px;
}
button{ width:70px;height:40px;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function map(lat,lon){
  // jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  var centerPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
  var options = {
    zoom: 16,
    center: centerPosition,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), options);
  //});
}
```

i didn't make test for it, just look through to check the syntax

i test it, your fiddle's issue

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>- jsFiddle demo</title>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
    <script type='text/javascript' src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&extension=.js"></script>
    <style type='text/css'>
        #map { height: 300px; width: 500px; }
        button { width: 70px; height: 40px;}
    </style>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        function map(lat, lon) {
            var centerPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
            var options = {
                zoom: 16,
                center: centerPosition,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), options);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <button onclick="map(15,90)">15 90</button>
    <button onclick="map(22,80)">22 80</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can find code like below in result frame "$(window).load(function(){" that's the issue